# Get error - "class wasn't found" when tryinng to run Java class

Tags: java, netbeans

When I run my program a prompt appears saying, "firstgame.FirstGame class wasn't found in FirstGame project.

```
public class FirstGame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Comment: Show us full codes. This is not full code.

Comment: have you defined a package?  error message says - `firstgame.FirstGame` and not only `FirstGame`

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: @SabirKhan I just had to define the package, can't believe it was something that simple. I'm not surprised if this website becomes my best friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in the beginning of your class package name, I think it is `FirstGame` in your case.

```
package FirstGame;
 public class FirstGame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```